# How to get value from dialog button to mainwindow tablewidget in pyqt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer

How can I get value from dialog button to mainwindow?

How can if the button on my dialog is pressed, give value to table widget on mainwindow?

Here my mainwindow code and dialog code, and code what I want to impact each other.

**mainwindow Code**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from ayam_ui import Ui_Dialog
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 0, 121, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Verdana")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setTextFormat(QtCore.Qt.AutoText)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 100, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 100, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 100, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 100, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(390, 100, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(550, 100, 231, 341))
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(2)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(10)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(4, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(5, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(6, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(7, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(8, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(9, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 0, item)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menumenu = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menumenu.setObjectName("menumenu")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menumenu.menuAction())
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.ayam)
    def pesanayam(self):
        item = self.tableWidget.item(0, 0)
        item.setText("ayam")
    def ayam(self):
        self.Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.Dialog)
        self.Dialog.show()
    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Kantin"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Makanan"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ayam"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Mie"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Sayur"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Daging"))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ikan"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText (_translate("mainwindows", "1"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Makanan"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "jumlah"))
        __sortingEnabled = self.tableWidget.isSortingEnabled()
        self.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(False)
        self.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)
        self.menumenu.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "menu"))
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**and this the dialog**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(348, 496)
        self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(Dialog)
        self.textBrowser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 280, 201, 201))
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")
        self.pesan = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pesan.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 300, 75, 23))
        self.pesan.setObjectName("pesan")
        self.spinBox = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(Dialog)
        self.spinBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 300, 42, 22))
        self.spinBox.setObjectName("spinBox")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 350, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, -10, 1351, 291))
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("E:/python/resto/ayy.jpg"))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(Dialog.close)
    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.textBrowser.setHtml(_translate("Dialog", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt; font-weight:600; text-decoration: underline;\">AYAM</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:12pt; font-weight:600; text-decoration: underline;\"><br /></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt; font-weight:600; text-decoration: underline;\">ini adalah ayam yang di goreng dengan minyak</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt; font-weight:600; text-decoration: underline;\">enak gurih dan renyah</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.pesan.setText(_translate("Dialog", "pesan"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "kembali"))
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

How can this button on the dialog

```
self.pesan = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pesan.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 300, 75, 23))
        self.pesan.setObjectName("pesan")
```

impact to this defintion on my main window?

```
def pesanayam(self):
        item = self.tableWidget.item(0, 0)
        item.setText("ayam")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from ayam_ui import Ui_Dialog

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 0, 121, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Verdana")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setTextFormat(QtCore.Qt.AutoText)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 100, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 100, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")

        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 100, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")

        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 100, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")

        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(390, 100, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")

        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(550, 100, 231, 341))
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(2)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(10)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(4, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(5, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(6, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(7, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(8, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(9, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 0, item)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menumenu = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menumenu.setObjectName("menumenu")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menumenu.menuAction())
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)

        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.ayam)

    def pesanayam(self):
        item = self.tableWidget.item(0, 0)
        item.setText(str(self.ui.spinBox.value()))  #("ayam")    # +++
        self.Dialog.hide()                                       # +++

    def ayam(self):
        self.Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.Dialog)
        self.ui.pesan.clicked.connect(self.pesanayam)            # +++
        self.Dialog.show()

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Kantin"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Makanan"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ayam"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Mie"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Sayur"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Daging"))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ikan"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText (_translate("mainwindows", "1"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Makanan"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "jumlah"))
        __sortingEnabled = self.tableWidget.isSortingEnabled()
        self.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(False)
        self.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)
        self.menumenu.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "menu"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: `self.ui.pesan.clicked.connect(self.pesanayam)`

thanks a lot this line very helpfull, also thanks for code show spinbox value